# Show that a random variable $T_x$ is uniformly distributed given that $T$ is uniformly distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

We have a lifetime $T$, which is uniformly distributed over $(0,b)$. We then introduce a new r.v., $T_x=T-x$, which is defined on $0<x<b$.

We want to show that given $T>x$, the variable $T_x$ is also uniformly distributed over $(0,b-x)$.

My understanding is that we're just shifting this variable. I feel like it's pretty obvious that it would still be uniform, since we're just consistently shifting the value of $T$ by the value of $x$ within the interval. However, I don't know how to go about showing this using notation consistent with probability theory. Any help or hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try not to give away the entire answer, but as you said it does *seem* pretty obvious. The issue is then converting this into rigorous mathematics! Let's proceed as follows.

We're interested in $P(T_x \le t)$, for varying $t$. Now, in terms of events,
$$ \{ T_x \le t \} \Leftrightarrow \{ T \le t + x \},$$
by definition of $T_x$, and so we know that $P(T_x \le t) = P(T \le t + x)$. But you know the distribution of $T$.

I'll stop here and see if you can finish (it's very nearly done). I can always add more details, should you require. :) -- I will give you a hint to remember that $T$ only takes values in $(0,b)$, so you need to be a little careful if $t > b-x \Leftrightarrow t+x > b$.

---

You want to look at $P(T_x \le t \mid T > x)$. You can use Bayes' formula/theorem to get this as
$$P(T_x \le t \mid T > x) = \frac{P(T_x \le t, T > x)}{P(T > x)} = \frac{P(x < T < t+x)}{P(T>x)} = \frac{P(T<t+x) - P(T<x)}{P(T>x)}.$$
Now substitute these for the numbers that you know, since you know the distribution of $T$.

In essence this question hinges on the correct application of Bayes' formula, and that $\{ T_x \le t \} \Leftrightarrow \{ T \le t + x \}$.

Comment: Okay, since it's expressed now in terms of $T$, we do know it's uniform...except maybe not when $t+x>b=t>b-x$. But since we're only asked to show that $T_x$ is uniform on $(0,b-x)$, aren't we done? The whole question almost seems moot to me haha. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, see it's not actually only uniform on $(0,b-x)$. Since $T$ takes the range $(0,b)$, $T-x$ takes the range $(-x,b-x)$. And yes, it is indeed uniform on this. You can see this by seeing that $P(T_x \le t)$ is $0$ for all $t \le -x$, $1$ for all $t \ge b-x$ and is distributed like $T$ between.

Comment: I do agree, however, that sometimes things seem really obvious, and it can be awkward to prove them! (That's where my applied maths / theoretical physics friend just says "it's obvious, so we'll assume it" and doesn't prove it! -- However, sometimes 'obvious' things are actually false, so we do need to prove them!)

Comment: That's true...I'm far enough along in my theoretical math career that I should know better than to say "it's obvious, QED!". To clarify, since $T_x$ is distributed as $T-x$ for $(x,b-x)$, is that the end of the proof? What about the conditional aspect?

Comment: Haha, I know what you mean! Are you clear on this now?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit about the conditional part! As my friend says, RTF -- read the full question (definitely what the saying normally is... =P). I've added some more to my answer.

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks :)